# How do I disable type-to-search in add menus in Blender 4.0?

Tags: interface

In previous versions of Blender, Add menus had hotkeys so you could quickly add an object with two keypresses, like so: https://blenderdaily.xyz/tips/underlined-letters

In Blender 4.0 this has been updated to be more user friendly, so typing instead starts searching by name for objects to add.  I find this quite annoying.

How do I restore the old behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, at least in 4.0. You can read discussion about that here: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/110855